# Checking Normality of Residuals

Tags: normal-distribution, multiple-regression, residuals, normality-assumption

I am trying to show, that my errors in my multiregression model is normally distributed. I have the values for Skewness and Kurtosis. Can I use Bowman Shelton test to show that?

Comment: You can use tests for normality, but in my experience qq plots are better

Comment: Check https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2492/is-normality-testing-essentially-useless

Comment: Thank you Niel van Zyl and Time. When using the qq plot and pp plot to show normality does it make a different if I square the residuals, because it seems that it is easier to see if I reject the normality condition or not?

Answer (score 0):

I would actually suggest a qq plot instead of a test. If you are working in R you can use:

```
qqnorm(errors)
qqline(errors)
```

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q%E2%80%93Q_plot) is more information on qq plots.

Comment: QQ plots are evocative, but I've never made a decision based on one. Could you give an example where a QQ plot causes you to make one decision and test would suggest that you make a different one? And how did you use the plot? This could be a *very* interesting answer.

Comment: Well, maybe it is just the way that I have been taught. In undergrad lecturers made us use tests for normality, where as in post grad they suggest that we rather use qq plots. I have been told that if the test yields a p-value of 0.1, you will still assume normality (testing at 5% significance). Using a qq plot for that same data one could easily see that it was skewed to the left. Unfortunately can't find the specific example that I am referring to now.

Comment: To clarify, I believe especially for small samples normality tests can be fairly inaccurate.